# Text and HTML on One Line

Tags: pug

In Jade, is it possible to create a single line for both text and HTML? For example I want to do the following:

```
<p><b>Format:</b> mp3</p>
```

and

```
<p>Format: <b>mp3</b></p>
```

I know how to do it multi line ...

```
p Format: 
    b #{string}
```

But, how is this possible on a single line?

Comment: I have show a few options in my answer below. And quick question to you - why do you need this in one line? Is is because you are concerned about performance or you prefer to read it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve one-line would be to use following code:

```
p Format: <b>#{string}</b>
```

That will give something like:

```
<p>Format: <b>2012</b></p>
```

If you did not have `Format:` label, you could also use following approach:

```
p: b= string
```

or

```
p: b #{string}
```

Both would return following HTML:

```
<p><b>2012</b></p>
```

I hope that will help.